# C# I want to make a program can copy a text from my pc to a Virtual machine

Tags: c#

What I have been trying to make is a program that takes a text input and then rewrites what is written, with a 3 second delay.

I have successfully made this program, so that it works on my own machine, but I want it to work, so that I can input text in it, and then target a notepad on a virtual machine. Is this possible?

What I have tried so far is:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        int time = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
        Thread.Sleep(time * 1000);
        SendKeys.Send((textBox1.Text));
    }
    catch
    {

        MessageBox.Show("Input text / time");
    }
}
```

This is in a Windows Forms App *.Net Framework 4.6.2*

Comment: What have you tried?  Edit your question to include a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Yes this is possible. You could use a program in the VM which communicates via the network, or shared directory, or other method - Or you could use a AutoHotkey style macro to type directly into the window

Comment: Just map a network drive.  Job done

Comment: @maccettura In a scenario where the OP likely doesn't actually know where to begin, "What have you tried" is not a very appropriate question, and If you want to know what his existing local-machine version of the program is, the right ask is "what is the version that works on your own machine", not "what have you tried".

Comment: @SamIam Don't you think arguing semantics is a little silly?  OP clearly said: " I have successfully made this program," but the original question contained 0 lines of code.  How do you expect the SO community to help answer a question when there is literally no details?

Comment: This question is way too broad for an answer. There are many ways to do this but the different solutions require different technologies, have different limitations and take different levels of effort.

Comment: @maccettura Semantics are quite important when soliciting extra information from someone.  Too often to I see people asking "what have you tried", and getting long blocks of totally wrong and unuseful code.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do, is you could have one program that runs on your VM, and one program that runs on your local machine that communicate over a virtual network.

The program on your local machine can send a request to the program on the VM, and upon receiving that request, the program on the VM, can run the same `SendKeys` functions that your existing program uses.

When I communicate over a network, I usually use [ASP.NET Web API](https://www.asp.net/web-api).  The tutorials on that should give you the knowledge to allow you to create a simple app that communicates over a network.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I should have explained my situation a bit better. I need this program to run on many VM's, so it has to be a program that has nothing to do with the VM.

Comment: @SkurkenHenning In that case, you likely have to look at the documentation for whatever hypervisor you're using, and see if it has an API call that allows you to send Keystrokes.